# How do I get a secret into a property file with openshift and kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, secret-management

I am new to openshift and kubernetes.

I have a secret in openshift and made it avaliable to the pod as an environment variable.

What is the *best practice* to get that value into a properies file (java) before the containers service starts?

Is there a better way than using `sed` on the propertyfile before startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can manage this :

- Like you said, make the secret data available trough environnement variables and run `sed` or `envsubst` on the file before startup.
- Or, you could create a secret that would hold your whole PropertyFile content, and then use that secret trough a `volume` to mount its content as a file in your Pod (see [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-pod-that-has-access-to-the-secret-data-through-a-volume) in the documentation for more informations). But since you only have one secret data in your PropertyFile, this might be overkill, depending on your setup.

I wouldn't know what option is the best in your situation, but these the one I would suggest.

Comment: I have worked with linux for 20 years, how have I never heard of envsubst before.